# python async function inside an async function

Tags: python, python-asyncio

My code:

```
import asyncio
from random import randrange

async def inner_sleep(letter, num):
    print(f'start inner sleep {letter}, {num}')
    myint = randrange(5)
    await asyncio.sleep(myint)
    print(f'done with inner sleep {letter}, {num}')

async def outer_sleep(letter):
    print(f'start outer sleep {letter}')
    myint = randrange(5)
    await asyncio.sleep(myint)
    print(f'done with outer sleep {letter}')

async def inside(letter):
    nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    tasks = []

    async def create_task(num):
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(inner_sleep(letter, num))
        tasks.append(task)
    
    for num in nums:
        await create_task(num)

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


async def outside():

    letters = ['a','b','c','d']
    tasks = []

    async def create_task_1(letter):
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(outer_sleep(letter))
        tasks.append(task)

    for letter in letters:
        await create_task_1(letter)
        await inside(letter)
    
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(outside())
```

Sample output:

```
start outer sleep a
start inner sleep a, 1
start inner sleep a, 2
start inner sleep a, 3
start inner sleep a, 4
start inner sleep a, 5
start inner sleep a, 6
done with inner sleep a, 4
done with outer sleep a
done with inner sleep a, 2
done with inner sleep a, 3
done with inner sleep a, 1
done with inner sleep a, 5
done with inner sleep a, 6
start outer sleep b
start inner sleep b, 1
start inner sleep b, 2
start inner sleep b, 3
start inner sleep b, 4
start inner sleep b, 5
start inner sleep b, 6
done with inner sleep b, 3
done with inner sleep b, 5
done with inner sleep b, 4
done with outer sleep b
done with inner sleep b, 1
done with inner sleep b, 6
done with inner sleep b, 2
start outer sleep c
start inner sleep c, 1
```

I have a loop inside a loop and I want both of them to run asynchronously. The inner one works correctly, but I'm having trouble getting the outer one to do what I want.  In the code above, I want my outer function to concurrently loop through the list 'letters'. For each letter, I need the first function (outer_sleep) to finish before the second function (inner_sleep) can start. I can't seem to find a place to put the inside function to accomplish this.  When I run this code, you can see in the results how 'inner sleep a' starts before 'done with outer sleep a'.  Ideally my output would look something like:

```
start outer sleep a
start outer sleep b
finish outer sleep a
start inner sleep a, 1
start inner sleep a, 2
start inner sleep a, 3
start inner sleep a, 4
start inner sleep a, 5
start inner sleep a, 6
finish outer sleep b
start inner sleep b, 1
start inner sleep b, 2
start inner sleep b, 3
start inner sleep b, 4
start inner sleep b, 5
start inner sleep b, 6
done with inner sleep a, 4
done with inner sleep a, 2
done with inner sleep b, 3
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

What about just placing `await inside(letter)` at the end of `outer_sleep`? This ensures it will only be run once the result of that specific `outer_sleep` has arrived.

```py
import asyncio
from random import randrange


async def inner_sleep(letter, num):
    print(f'start inner sleep {letter}, {num}')
    myint = randrange(5)
    await asyncio.sleep(myint)
    print(f'done with inner sleep {letter}, {num}')


async def inside(letter):
    nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(inner_sleep(letter, num)) for num in nums]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


async def outer_sleep(letter):
    print(f'start outer sleep {letter}')
    myint = randrange(5)
    await asyncio.sleep(myint)
    print(f'done with outer sleep {letter}')
    await inside(letter)


async def outside():
    letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(outer_sleep(letter)) for letter in letters]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


asyncio.run(outside())
```

The `asyncio.gather` means that both the numbers as well as the letters can be processed in any order (e.g. 'c' can come before 'b'), if that's okay with you.

Answer (score 1):

In `create_task_1` you're calling `outer_sleep` but you don't `await` the result. This means that the task is started but the execution of the `outside` function proceeds before it completes.

Is there a reason you need the `create_task_1` function? Can you just `await outer_sleep(letter)` directly instead? For example (note this is untested):

```
async def outside():

    letters = ['a','b','c','d']
    
    # don't need create_task_1 funciton anymore

    for letter in letters:
        await outer_sleep(letter)
        await inside(letter)
    
    # don't need to gather the tasks as they're already complete
```

*Edit*:

You clarified in the comments that you want all of the `outer_sleep` tasks to start at the same time. You just need to flip around the order of execution a little

```
async def outside():

    letters = ['a','b','c','d']
    tasks = []

    async def task_1(letter):
        await outer_sleep(letter)
        await inside(letter)

    for letter in letters:
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(task_1(letter))
        tasks.append(task)
    
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Comment: that does help ensure that outer_sleep finishes before inner_sleep, however it doesn't make the loop through letters asynchronous as well. i want to gather the whole loop through letters so that when it's awaiting the outer_sleep function for 'a', it can move on to start the outer_sleep for 'b'.

Comment: You can’t really achieve that with a for loop. You’ll need something like `asyncio.gather`.